# Looking for the path of a particular file provided by a particular rpm in a spec

Tags: rpm

I want to know the path of `apxs` provided by `httpd-devel`, on a machine that might have other copies of `apxs`, that would be resolved by `which` first. I can be reasonably confident this command will work:

```
rpm -ql httpd-devel | egrep 's?bin/apxs2?$'
```

However, is there a way to test without piping through `grep` and regex?

Comment: Do you want to know the directory that `apxs` resides in. That isn't clear from your Q. Can you please rephrase it? Also you shouldn't be using `which`. Use the command `type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the unix way to do it - piping output from one program to another in order to use small buildin blocks to achieve what you need.

Comment: I know that's the unix way of doing things, just wondering if rpm has a better query syntax built in. `gzip -d foo.tar.gz | tar -xvvf -` is more unixy than `tar -xzvvf`, but I still think the second way is superior (one less process to spawn, no IPC overhead, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; it wasn't clear from your question what exactly you were looking for. Your example is a good one, since gnutar is quite a bit larger than the old tar that doesn't have built-in gzip, meaning that the second one isn't necessarily more efficient after all. Sometimes having small separate modules allows for efficiency gains that offset the IPC overhead.

Comment: @JustinDearing, [OT] some implementations of `tar` like GNU `tar` (which was the first one to add the `z` flag I believe) do call `gzip` with a pipe in a separate process with the `z` flag.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas and Jenny good points.

Comment: @JustinDearing Thanks, you too have a good point - I just didn't understand it until you clarified. IPC does add some overhead, but how much will depend on many factors. Thinking about the reasons for different ways of doing things is always useful - I tend to like the unix modular approach, but there are certainly times when it's not the most efficient one.

Answer (score 1):

#### Directory of file in RPM

Your questions is a bit confusing. If you're asking about how to determine the path of the file that's contained in a specific RPM then no, there is no way to do this using just `rpm` or `yum`.

This is one way to get the path of `apxs` from a RPM.

```
$ dirname $(rpm -ql httpd-devel | grep "apxs$")
/usr/bin
```

#### Files contained in an RPM

If your question is about how to find out if a file is present in a given RPM then there are 3 methods that I'm familiar with when determining whether a file on disk belongs to a RPM.

#### Method #1 - Query the RPM DB

```
$ rpm -ql httpd-devel | grep "apxs$"
/usr/bin/apxs
```

#### Method #2 - see which RPM a file belongs to

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/sbin/apxs
httpd-devel-2.2.22-jason.1
```

#### Method #3 - whatprovides

You can query the RPM DB like this using `yum whatprovides ..`.

#### Example

```
$ yum whatprovides '*apxs'
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
httpd-devel-2.4.4-6.fc19.i686 : Development interfaces for the Apache HTTP server
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/apxs



httpd-devel-2.4.4-6.fc19.x86_64 : Development interfaces for the Apache HTTP server
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/apxs



httpd-devel-2.4.6-2.fc19.i686 : Development interfaces for the Apache HTTP server
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/apxs



httpd-devel-2.4.6-2.fc19.x86_64 : Development interfaces for the Apache HTTP server
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/apxs



httpd-devel-2.4.6-2.fc19.x86_64 : Development interfaces for the Apache HTTP server
Repo        : @updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/apxs
```

Comment: The first method is exactly what I did, and the second method doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: @JustinDearing - I realize that, I was showing you all the potential methods. Those are what's available. Don't kill the messenger. I've been using RH distros for 20+ yrs. this is what you have.

Comment: @JustinDearing - you can do a `locate apxs`, and run that through a loop or `rpm -qf $i`.